# Can I be sure that Identity column in SQL Server will never get a value between existing values?

Tags: sql-server, event-sourcing

For context: thinking about a simplified "event store" table for use in our preexisting CRUD db.

The Events table would have a BIGINT IDENTITY primary key, which would also serve as the "position" of the event in the event log.

First of all because all the questions I could find with related keywords discussed gaps: I do not care about gaps, if the identity cache causes a jump from 12 to 1001, that is not an actual problem. The only important thing about gaps is that they should never be filled.

The question is: Can I ever run into a scenario where there are multiple inserts into the table from concurrent sources, and from the read side a row appears with identity value below an already existing identity value?

For example, if I create a service that wants to handle all rows inserted into the table, can I save locally the largest identity value of the already handled rows, and be sure, that if next time I ask for rows with identity values larger than the saved value, I will never miss a row that got inserted between existing identity values due to concurrency?

From my understanding, this is a sane and bomb proof assumption because the IDENTITY value is supposed to be filled out upon execution of the insert and there is no mechanism to reuse skipped values. But I dont have enough experience with SQL server to not question if there is some finicky edge case / specific implementation detail that

1. breaks this assumption altogether?
2. neccesiates some extra configuration to ensure this?
3. if this works by default, is there some configuration / T-SQL command that could break it and should be avoided?

Comment: I think you’re asking if it can be used as a high watermark and the answer is yes. If you capture the value at t1, then all records inserted after this time will have a higher value.

Comment: Note that sequences are available if you find yourself in need of more control, have to synchronize things across databases, want to reserve ranges of numbers reliably, or if you'd like to be able to assign numbers without necessarily having to insert rows. They are not necessarily better than a simple identity column if you don't need any of that, but still worth considering.

Comment: If you want all the rows inserted since the last time you checked, use _the last time you checked_ as a watermark, not some arbitrary surrogate key assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lower values will never be "filled in" unless someone reseeds via [`DBCC CHECKIDENT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql) (or [truncates the table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/truncate-table-transact-sql)), or overrides the default identity assignment using [`SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql).

However, if you have two sessions that have transaction control, it all depends on what you mean by "first" - it is theoretically possible that one transaction can spend more time before getting and committing their value, and the other transaction can spend more time after, so the one that started or finished "first" (again depending on how you measure that) actually got a later value. Let's say you have this table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.what;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.what
(
  id      int       IDENTITY(1,1), 
  spid    int       NOT NULL DEFAULT @@SPID,
  txStart datetime2 NOT NULL DEFAULT sysdatetime()
);
GO
```

Then open two new query windows. In window 1, start this:

```
-- start this one first, but make it wait
SELECT status = 'Starting time', ts = sysdatetime();

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:30';
INSERT dbo.what DEFAULT VALUES;
COMMIT TRANSACTION;

SELECT status = 'Committed time', ts = sysdatetime();

SELECT id, spid, txStart, 
    [mine?] = CASE spid WHEN @@SPID THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END
  FROM dbo.what;
```

Then, in window #2, start this:

```
-- start this one second
SELECT status = 'Starting time', ts = sysdatetime();

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT dbo.what DEFAULT VALUES;
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:45';
COMMIT TRANSACTION;

SELECT status = 'Committed time', ts = sysdatetime();

SELECT id, spid, txStart, 
    [mine?] = CASE spid WHEN @@SPID THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END
  FROM dbo.what;
```

Your results should be something like this, showing that the transaction that committed first actually got the higher identity value:

[image]

Without transactions or other delay possibilities in place, then no, first in wins, and the earliest insert will always have the lowest identity value. That said, it would be safer to rely on application timestamp if you need to be sure that app 1's event, which you know happened first, gets properly slotted before app 2's event, which you know happened a microsecond later. Order by that value you know, rather than relying on assumptions about the sequencing of arbitrary, surrogate identifier assignment. IMHO.

Comment: I dont actually care about the insertion order on the write side (or if I do, it is handled at a higher level, so if two concurrent writes are happening, it is assumed that their completion order is not interesting) Your helpfully concise example however nicely demonstrates that what I do care about is easily violated with transactions (eg.: if a query ran between 33:26 and 33:43 it would have showed one row with id=2 then after 33:43 a new query would show a new 'backfilled' id of 1